# Can't capture image with mobile camera from external page which is loaded to INTEL XDK mobile app

Tags: cordova, intel-xdk

I have page on web server which containing code to capture image from mobile camera. Problem is when I load that page with InAppBrowser plugin in mobile app created in INTEL XDK. In that case it doesn't work. Only work when I go directly to taht page thru the browser

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to the fact that when you are opening the page using the inAppBrowser you are probably opening your page within the mobile app webview, which is not equivalent to opening your page in the mobile browser, for a variety of reasons.

I recommend that you first check to make sure the "optimize with Crosswalk" option is checked, which insures your webview is an up-to-date webview. If that makes no difference, then use the [inAppBrowser "_system" option](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser#cordovainappbrowseropen), in order to open your page in the mobile browser.